# Proper map on compact Riemann surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

i hope you can help me with a problem I discovered while dealing with the resolution of singularities for an algebraic curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$.

A resolution means for me, that for an algebraic curve $C$ you've got a compact Riemann surface $S$ and a proper map $\pi:S \rightarrow C$, such that $\pi|_{S-Sing(C))}$ is a biholomorphism.

Now I want to proof, that $S$ is unique up to biholomorphic equivalence. The only thing I'm not sure in that proof is, that for $x \in Sing(C)$ the preimage $\pi^{-1}(\{x\})$ is discrete and therefore since $\pi$ is a proper map finite.

Am I able to proof this assertion? And if I should be how can I do so?

Comment: Locally at any point $y\in \pi^{-1}(x)$, $S$ is an open disc and $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is the zero set of some holomorphic function, so $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is discrete. 

Regarding your comment, that compact Riemann surfaces are algebraic is a hard theorem (existence of non-constant meromorphic functions on $S$).

Comment: Ok, that argument looks like that for a nonconstant holomorphic function between two compact Riemann surfaces. But I in this case $C$ isn't a Riemann surface, is it? Also I don't know the holomorphic function $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is the zero set of, you are talking about.

Comment: How do you define a map $\pi$ ?

Comment: $\pi:S \rightarrow C$ is proper and therefore continuous, where $S$ is a Riemann surface. Furthermore $\pi|_{S-\pi^{-1}(Sing(C))}:S-\pi^{-1}(Sing(C)) \rightarrow C-Sing(C)$ is biholomorphic. I hope that's what you meant.

Comment: A map of complex varieties is defined locally by holomorphic functions. What I said is true for any map from a Riemann surface to a complex variety.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is (Zariski) closed and $S$ is irreducible. Therefore $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is either 0 or 1 dimensional. If it were $1$ dimensional, then it would be equal to $S$.

Another way of showing that $S$ is unique is the following way: If $\pi':S'\to C$ is another non-singular curve that satisfies the same thing, then by taking away all singular points in $C$ and in the preimage of $\pi$ and $\pi'$, we get a birational map $(\pi')^{-1}\circ\pi:S\to S'$. But the place where a birational map between non-singular projective varieties is not defined is of codimension greater than or equal to 2. Therefore, this map is defined everywhere. Since a map between two non-singular curves has a degree that is well defined, and the birational map above is generically 1-1, we have that it is actually an isomorphism.

Comment: Here I'm assuming the fact that compact Riemann surfaces are algebraic curves.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that compact Riemann surfaces are algebraic curves but I haven't proofed it yet so I would prefer not to use it. I'd like to have a different - let's say elementary - way to get the fact that $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is finite. Anyway I'm very greatful for your help! And also I hope to do right by creating a new answer. If I did wrong just let me know. It's my first post here.

Comment: @MoZ You should post a comment in order to reply to an answer, rather than creating a new answer. It also seems that you have created two accounts named "Mo Z". You should merge these accounts if possible, in order to give yourself ownership of this question (and as a consequence, the ability to comment). Instructions for merging can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).